# Allowing users to delete their own comments in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For each post, there are postcomments.

Here's what the model for the Postcomment looks like:

```
class Postcomment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and the Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :image, :comment_content
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :postcomments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I would like to allow users to delete their own postcomments. This is what I already have in the view

_postcomment.html.erb

```
<% if post.postcomments.exists? %>
  <% post.postcomments.each do |postcomment| %>
    <%= link_to postcomment.user.name, postcomment.user %>
    <span class="content2"><%= postcomment.postcomment_content %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How should this code below be changed to allow users to delete comments?

```
 <% if current_user?(postcomment.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", postcomment.content, method: :delete,
                                             confirm: "You sure?",
                                             title: postcomment.content %>
 <% end %>
```

`current_user` methods in Sessions helper

```
def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
```

Here's the Postcomments table

```
 create_table "postcomments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text      "content"
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.integer   "post_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at",      :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.text      "comment_content"
  end
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Does it give an error? Does it not let users delete their comments?

Comment: it doesn't give an error... but the "delete" text doesn't show up next to the comments

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: No i'm not. I have my own very basic authentication system

Comment: Can you post your `current_user?` method then?

Comment: def current_user `@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])` end

Comment: I don't see how `current_user?` accepts an argument.

Comment: I just updated the original post, does that help?

Comment: Why don't you binding.pry in the current_user? method? You would then be able to check your current_user value as well as the user value, figuring out what your problem is.

Comment: I can get the "delete" to show up, but when I try to delete the comment, it stays put. Anyone know what `postcomment.content` should be changed to?

Comment: Can you post your destroy method for comments ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps...

if current_user == postcomment.user

If current_user returns a user instance anyways...

Answer (score 1):

It might be better if you just compared the user id's. This is also easier to debug.

```
def current_user?(user)
  user.id == current_user.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
<%= link_to("delete", postcomment.content, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", :title => postcomment.content) if postcomment.user == current_user %>
```

Comment: I can get "delete" to show up but the postcomment stays put. Any idea what `postcomment.content` should be set to so that the comments actually get deleted?

Comment: @user2159586 So in other words, there's nothing wrong with the logic, just the delete link itself. Do you have jquery-ujs enabled? Delete requests are handled using JavaScript.

Comment: The postcomments themselves are displayed in a jquery popup so jquery is enabled. I feel that deleting `postcomment.content` is not working. I updated the original post with the postcomments table. Does the delete code line seem right to you?