# How to limit someone to deleting their own comment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, blogs

I am very new to Rails. I completed a tutorial [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) that walks you through the steps of creating a blog using it.

Part of the tutorial shows you how to create a controller that allows users to add comments to an article. I am trying to modify it so that users can only delete their own comments (and not others' comments).

**Question:**
Is there a way to modify the code so that way you can limit users to deleting their own comments? Any resources/tutorials are welcome too. I really just have no clue on how to start.

I feel like the right way to go is to mark the user some way when they submit the comment. Save that information in the database, and then check that information when someone goes to delete a comment. But I can't think of a way to do that without trying to build a full on log in system for users.

**Code:**
Here is the code from the tutorial:

Database Migration:

```
    class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :comments do |t|
          t.string :commenter
          t.text :body
          t.references :article, index: true, foreign_key: true

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

Template:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Delete Comment:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)

    redirect_to article_path(@article)

  end

 

  def destroy

    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])

    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])

    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to article_path(@article)

  end

 

  private

    def comment_params

      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)

    end

end
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041994/allowing-users-to-delete-their-own-comments-in-rails-3), but there wasn't an answer that worked.

Comment: where is your destroy method or delete code ?

Comment: Looks like _write code for me_, i can't find any efforts where you try to delete a user.

Comment: @Зелёный I edited the question to make it clearer. The problem is I don't know where to start. That's why I tried to explain what I think I could do. So there is no code attempting that. And I'm not trying to delete a user, I'm just trying to have them delete their own comment. Like on SO. If you write a comment, I shouldn't be able to delete it (just like you shouldn't be able to delete mine).

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli I added my delete code (from the tutorial).

Comment: @JustBlossom You should just store the commenter's IP address in the DB, then check that when attempting to delete. This would be the best way to do it without creating a login system (which it sounds like you do not want to do)

Answer (score 2):

In CommentsController Edit your destroy method like below :

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
  if @comment.user.id == current_user.id
   flash[:success] = "Comment Deleted Successfully!"
   @comment.destroy
  else
   flash[:error] = "You can only delete your own comments!"
  end
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

**Add a migration to add user_id to the comment table** :

```
class AddUserIdToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

**Comment & User Model should be like below to track the user from comment :**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

**View:**

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

**In Comment Controller change comment_params**

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: if comment belongs_to user, comment.user.id will always equal comment.user_id

Comment: @srecnig i have updated answer check now, it was just a mistype.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying to get it to work, but I'm getting the following error "NoMethodError in CommentsController#destroy undefined method `user'" So, I tried replacing it with @comment.commenter, but that's not right. That means you'll end up with the same problem srecnig mentioned.

Comment: @JustBlossom You should add proper relation for comment and user as currently in comment table there is not user_id so thats why its not working.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli Thanks for your help. I marked the answer up bc it was helpful; it just didn't work. I added everything including creating a new migration. Now, I am getting an error that says "NoMethodError in CommentsController#destroy
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass." When I take "belongs_to :user" out of my comments controller, I get this error, "NoMethodError in CommentsController#destroy undefined method `user' for #<Comment:...>" But it's there. I created a user.rb file in models file and placed the user class code in it. Is there something else I need to do to link that file?

Comment: you can try `@comment.user_id == current_user.id` & make sure you are saving user_id in `CommentsController#create` method in comment record. also debug if `current_user` is present or not.